# How to delete all instances of a character in a bunch of files?

Tags: files, text-editing, replace, keyboard-macros

I was given a directory of files in which I was asked to make some systematic changes. Because it was a one-off task, and because there were only a few hundred files I thought I'd use an Emacs keyboard macro.

My macro, in addition to making the desired changes, placed a bunch of `!` in the buffer (since I was trying to answer a query about whether to replace an instance of pattern match with a declaration tell emacs to replace all instances, and if no instances were found it just inserted an `!`).

Is there a nice simple way of getting rid of all these `!` using another keyboard macro and/or some simple `elisp`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you *want* an interactive confirmation, which you presumably don't since you're automatic the replacement of all occurrences, call [`replace-string`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Unconditional-Replace.html#index-replace_002dstring) or [`replace-regexp`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html#index-replace_002dregexp) instead of `query-replace-string` or `query-replace-regexp`.

But you don't need a macro at all to perform the same replacement in several files. Open the directory containing the files in [Dired](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html#Dired) (just use the normal way you open files, and select the directory). If there are several directories, you can use [`find-dired` or one of its variants](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-and-Find.html#Dired-and-Find), or [press `i` to insert a subdirectory](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Subdirectories-in-Dired.html#Subdirectories-in-Dired). Mark the files where you want to perform the replacements: you can use [`m`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Marks-vs-Flags.html#index-m-_0028Dired_0029) to mark the current file, or other commands such as [`% m`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Marks-vs-Flags.html#index-dired_002dmark_002dfiles_002dregexp) to mark the files based on a regular expression for their name. Then press [`Q`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Operating-on-Files.html#index-Q-_0028Dired_0029) to perform a regexp replacement in all the files. This is interactive, but you can press `Y` to validate the replacement in all files.

Answer (score 2):

```
man tr
```

Your entire task is a one-line bash command. 
I wouldn't bother using Emacs for it.

```
for f in * ; do mv $f tmp ; tr -d '!' < tmp > $f ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I'll assume you already can run a macro in all the files, if not, a handy trick is to create a list of files in one buffer, and create a macro that opens an item in the list and ends with the cursor at the next item.  A simple search and replace removing `!` would leave you with the same problem, since any file without `!` would get one inserted.

A simple solution is to replace `!` with `!`, which ensures that the character exists in every file, then run search and replace to remove it completely.